# netbeans php go to variable assignment for class attribute (rather than declaration)

Tags: php, netbeans

In netbeans, I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click a variable name to jump to the declaration of that variable. This works great for normal variables. However, when I use it for a class attribute, it jumps me to the top of the class to a line like

`private $myVar;`

which is technically correct, but pretty much useless. It would be much more helpful if it jumped me to the line where the variable is first assigned a value, ie

`$this->$myVar=7;`

**Is this possible? If so, how?**

*Using NetBeans 8.0.2 on Windows 7*

Comment: bounty description should say "...press on **a class property variable**..."

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for StackOverflow. It's more suited to something like http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Phil I would agree that in general for questions about a piece of software, they would probably be a better fit on SuperUser, but specifically questions about an IDE or a non-IDE code editor like notepad++, StackOverflow makes sense, since this site is home to the people most likely to have answers to IDE related questions, and also as evidenced by all of these questions currently on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans%20or%20notepad%2b%2b%20or%20phpstorm%20or%20android-studio%20or%20sublime%20or%20xcode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as far as I know and as I have tried, this is not possible.

Because, a variable can be defined once, but can be initialized/assigned at multiple places. How will you say as which one is **first**?

For Example, I may be initializing the variable in the **constructor** method or I may be having a **setter** method to set the variable without the **contructor** too, or I may be having entirely a different method, not specifically **constructor**, which I may be calling to set values for variables. So there may be a chance that I have all these in my code.

Hence it's not possible.

Comment: "first" could easily be defined as the earliest line number in the class where it is assigned a value

Comment: whether or not that is correct, such as in the situation you describe of setting in a constructor or a setter, it is still MUCH more useful that the property declaration at the top of the class

Comment: Hi @chiliNUT, I completely agree to what you said that it is good to declare at top class. What I have given are just scenarios as how people may code in different ways, where the feature implementation may be difficult. But yes this feature will be useful ;-).

Comment: but now that we have it nailed down (goto earliest line number in file of the variable assignment) can this be accomplished with a setting or a macro?

Comment: Hi @chiliNUT, am not sure about the SETTING but may be using the **Regular Expression** based macro, we may have to try. Sorry, beyond this I may not be of much useful. Wish, I would have helped you more than this.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I couldn't figure it out with NetBeans macro language since I don't know how to grab the selection, modify it, and do a regex search for it, which seems like that is needed. I was able to do it with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). The idea is to make a macro which does the following:

1. Double click at the caret position to highlight the property name. Netbeans wasn't reporting its caret position, so I have to settle for using the mouse position, which is fine.
2. Create the following regex to locate when **`propName`** gets a value assigned:

`\$this\s*\->\s*propName\s*=`

3. Then, do a search for that regex, and go to the first instance found.

It's not perfect, but its a start and it seems to be working out for me. It currently won't work for nested properties (`$this->someProp->subProp`) could locate `someProp` but not `subProp` (it would incorrectly search for `$this->subProp`) but it should be able to handle those too by adjusting the regex.

I have assigned the macro to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> in the following:

```
!~LButton Up::
; //save the old clipboard
oldClipboard := Clipboard
; //Sleep a while. Without this, the double click overlaps with the 
; //original click used to trigger the macro, 
; //and the wrong text is highlighted (usually the thole line)
Sleep 500
Click 2 ;
; //Copy the text
Send ^c
searchText := Clipboard
; //prefix it with this regex: "\$this\s*\-\>\s*" and add "\s*=" to the end so varName becomes \$this\s*\-\>\s*varName\s*=
searchText := "\$this\s*\-\>\s*" . searchText . "\s*="
Sleep 50
; //Toggle search dialog
Send ^f
Sleep 50
; //write the text into the form
Send %searchText% 
Loop, 2 {
Sleep 100
Send !g ; //turn regex on or off
; //since the state of whether regex is on or off is not known, cycle thru both

Sleep 100
Send {Enter}
}

; //restore the clipboard
 Clipboard := oldClipboard

return
```